# Java Servlet filter: I have to add headers before passing to the chain, documentation tells otherwise

Tags: java, servlets, filter

We're currently working on adding headers to each response from our application. To add these headers we're using the Servlet APIs `Filter`-interface.

We've got the following filter in our application:

```
public class SecurityFilter implements Filter
{
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);

        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = ((HttpServletResponse) response);
        httpServletResponse.addHeader("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
        httpServletResponse.addHeader("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy()
    {

    }
}
```

This (specifically the `doFilter`-method) is implemented correctly according to the documentation, which suggests the following order of work:

> 1. Examine the request
> 2. Optionally wrap the request object with a custom implementation to filter content or headers for input filtering
> 3. Optionally wrap the response object with a custom implementation to filter content or headers for output filtering
> 4. - Either invoke the next entity in the chain using the FilterChain object (chain.doFilter()),
>    - or not pass on the request/response pair to the next entity in the filter chain to block the request processing
> 5. Directly set headers on the response after invocation of the next entity in the filter chain.

As far as we can see, the order of our `doFilter`-method is correct according to the documentation (pass the request to the chain first as stated under point 4, add custom headers afterwards as stated under point 5). However, the headers we add aren't visible in the responses. If we change to order to the following, everything seems to work just fine:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
{
    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = ((HttpServletResponse) response);
    httpServletResponse.addHeader("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
    httpServletResponse.addHeader("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: Are there any other filters?

Comment: @EvanKnowles there are. I think that was part of the problem, as Nikos Paraskevopoulos pointed out below another filter most likely commits the request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know what version of the Servlet spec are you referring to, but in 3.1, chapter 6.2.1 "Filter Lifecycle" I read (emphasis mine):

> 5. After invocation of the next filter in the chain, the filter may **examine** response headers.

"Examine" not "set"! Actually, the spec for the header methods says (Servlet 3.1, chapter 5.2 "Headers"):

> To be successfully transmitted back to the client, headers must be set before the response is committed. Headers set after the response is committed will be ignored by the servlet container.

I guess this is happening to your request, some servlet or filter down the chain is "committing", so headers are ignored.

**Bottom line:** The spec (at least as far as I can see in 3.1) does not suggest to set the headers after calling `chain.doFilter()`. Your second version that works is correct (and how I've always implemented filters that add headers)!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've just committed the change after we've read the documentation for spec 3.0 the documentation is the same as you've quoted.

Silly how the code comments use a confusing description for the `doFilter`-method though...

Answer (score 5):

Oracle tells you to wrap the response before passing it down the chain, if you want to add something after `chain.doFilter(..)`

> Note that if you want to preprocess the request object or postprocess
>   the response object, you cannot directly manipulate the original
>   request or response object. You must use wrappers. When postprocessing
>   a response, for example, the target servlet has already completed and
>   the response could already be committed by the time a filter would
>   have a chance to do anything with the response. **You must pass a
>   response wrapper instead of the original response in the chain
>   doFilter() call.** See "Using a Filter to Wrap and Alter the Request or
>   Response".

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B32110_01/web.1013/b28959/filters.htm#BCFCIHAH